# Alasql - How to create multiple worksheets into a workbook?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alasql

I'm trying to export data to excel workbook with multiple sheets.
I had a look at the following:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ry8fq0dL/
- https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/How-to-create-multiple-worksheets-into-a-workbook

The jsfiddle example works as is, But as soon as I change the lib to use the latest lib it is not working any more.

Replacing:

```
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
```

With:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.2.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.2.3/alasql-worker.min.js"></script>
```

I'm working on a AngularJS project and need to export data to excel workbook with multiple sheets. If anyone knows a way to do this please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep

```
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sd7822df/

Please only include alasql-worker.min.js if you need it to ron as a webworker... - and avoid including alasq.min.js if you include alasql-worker.min.js

Comment: I created a codepen if anyone is interested, making use of AngularJS, http://codepen.io/DickSwart/pen/wWPYpX/